# CROSS JOIN with temp table and CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm trying to `CROSS JOIN` a table with a view. Here is my code:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM   ( SELECT    * ,
                    CASE TypeId
                      WHEN 1 THEN InGs828S
                      WHEN 2 THEN InGS828H
                      WHEN 3 THEN InGS828L
                      WHEN 4 THEN InEasyFlowWD
                    END AS InDevice
          FROM      dbo.Ports
        ) tempTable
        CROSS JOIN dbo.vwDevices
WHERE InDevice=1
```

I get `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Invalid column name 'TypeId'`.  `TypeId` is a column in view `vwDevices`.

My question is why can't I use any columns from `vwDevices` in `CASE *ColName*`, while I can use columns from table `Ports`?

Comment: Your CASE is equivalent to the following: CASE TypeId
                      WHEN 1 THEN InGs828S
                    END AS InDevice

I am not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: My case statement was incomplete, I've edited my question.

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov: My case statement was incomplete, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it the other way around:

```
SELECT *
 FROM  dbo.vwDevices AS v
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    * ,
                    CASE v.TypeId
                      WHEN 1 THEN InGs828S
                      WHEN 2 THEN InGS828H
                      WHEN 3 THEN InGS828L
                      WHEN 4 THEN InEasyFlowWD
                    END AS InDevice
          FROM      dbo.Ports
        ) AS tempTable
WHERE tempTable.InDevice=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another way of rewriting your query (a join too, like in [@gbn's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/22354/6965), but the CASE expression is replaced with a disjunction of conjunctions):

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Ports p
  INNER JOIN dbo.vwDevices d
     ON p.TypeId = 1 AND p.InGs828S = 1
     OR p.TypeId = 2 AND p.InGs828H = 1
     OR p.TypeId = 3 AND p.InGs828L = 1
     OR p.TypeId = 4 AND p.InEasyFlowWD = 1
```

Comment: Disjunction of conjunctions is a phrase I need to find excuses to use!

Answer (score 1):

You'd need CROSS APPLY to plug in columns from another table

However, are you sure you need it at all?

```
SELECT *
FROM
    dbo.vwDevices D
    INNER JOIN
    dbo.Ports P ON 
                   CASE D.TypeId
                      WHEN 1 THEN P.InGs828S
                      WHEN 2 THEN P.InGS828H
                      WHEN 3 THEN P.InGS828L
                      WHEN 4 THEN P.InEasyFlowWD
                    END = 1
```

Comment: Neither `cross join` nor `cross apply` have an `on` clause?

Comment: @Andomar: cross join no, cross apply needs some correlation

Comment: @gbn: your provided code is wrong and causes syntax error.

Comment: @gbn: Please check my question again I've updated case statment

Comment: @gbn: I think you meant either `JOIN ... ON` or `CROSS JOIN ... WHERE`